# GAE Python: How to acquire user name and additional information?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a question regarding the user api for GAE Python.

For a new application for an already existing user base I would like to get two informations for a user. First is the name and the second would be a flag (0,1 or 2 in example).

It's an internal application and only people from the same domain can login. How can I access their information beyond whats in the [users reference](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userclass)? And how could I set that additional flag?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from the `User` class you may get only the information it provides, everything else you have to solicit directly from your users using some kind of "Accounts" page, where they can input their name and/or change the value of a flag.

This information can be saved in the database as a separate entity `UserData`, preferably alond with user `email` or `user_id` received from the `User` class. Something along the lines of:

```
class UserData(db.Model) :
    user = db.UserProperty()
    name = db.StringProperty()
    flag = db.IntegerProperty()
```